# Filter with association "BelongsTo" and "HasMany" with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, filter, associations, cakephp-3.x

I code a little project with CakePHP.

My problem is that I want to filter some data with others tables' attributes and those tables have different associations with the main table. Some have association `belongsTo` with it and some have `hasMany`.

For the `belongsTo` I use this syntax for filter:

```php
if (!empty($search)) {
  $words = explode(' ', $search);
  foreach ($words as $word) {
    $arraySearch = [];
    foreach ($this->searchFields as $searchField) {
      $arraySearch[$searchField . ' LIKE'] = "%$word%";
    }
    $query->where(['OR' => $arraySearch]);
  }
}
```

And for `hasMany` I use:

```php
$words = explode(' ', $search);
foreach ($words as $word) {
  $query->matching('IssueComments', function ($q) use ($word) {
    return $q->where(['IssueComments.comment LIKE' => "%$word%"]);
  });
}
```

And I don't know how to combine those two syntaxes, because I want to merge the filters' results `belongsTo` and `hasMany`.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I can only assume that by "_combine_" you mean your filters should apply in an OR manner, eg "_where words are either in `belongsTo` or in `hasMany` association_"?

Comment: That's exactly what I want.